# React: Are props objects passed automatically to children components or does there always exist some default props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

Does there exist some default props object that is always passed from parent component down to a child component?

I know one can pass props to some children components from a parent component, like:

```
<div>
<ChildComponent color="blue" otherProp=false />
</div>
```

and access them in child component via `props.color` and `props.otherProp`...
but what if I don't create props for my child component, does there still exist some default `props` object (or maybe some props meta object) with additional information for that child component?

E.g I have seen some match object that gets automatically created by the React-router library and passed down to its components that are rendered when matching some route path, e.g:

```
<Route path={`${match.path}/:name`}
  render= {({match}) =>( <div> <h3> {match.params.name} </h3></div>)}/>
```

I was just wondering where in this example, the  `({match})` object is coming from when its passed as a parameter to the render prop function....

Comment: You should take a look at [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

Comment: hmm I didnt understand that part:         `<Mouse render={mouse => (
          <Cat mouse={mouse} />
        )}/>`  what is this `{mouse =>` parameter that gets passed to the function ? Is it a placeholder for the `event` object?  that gets fired when `onMouseMove` event gets fired? I dont see the connection with `{this.props.render(this.state)}` in the Mouse component

Comment: EDIT: ok I think I got it, `mouse` is the `this.state` object that gets passed from Mouse Component's `this.props.render` function, which itself gets passed to the cat component...

Answer (score 2):

If you dont pass the props to the child components, they wont be available to the child component period. Have a look at render [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

Incase of `Route` in react router, the `Route` passes its props to the children props using [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). So the props of `Route` will be available to the immediate child component but wont be available to the next child component hierarchy.

Example:

```
<Route props={props}>
   <Child1>
       will have props
       <Child2>
         will not have props if not passed from Child1
       </Child2>
   </Child1>
</Route>
```